# When using a Project Access Token, I'm getting "The requested URL returned error: 403"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I try to use a project access token, I'm getting

```
$ git clone https://asdf:token@acme.com/evancarroll/foo.git
Cloning into 'foo'...
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://acme.com/evancarroll/foo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this was because the token I was creating, though it had the `read_repository` and `write_repository` permissions, it was not set to the role of "Developer" or higher.

**Recreating the token with the role of Developer instead of Guest solved the problem for me.**